# Why isn't my nested SQL SELECT INTO statement working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

The basic SELECT INTO statement works, but I need to get the TransactionNumbers in another table where the date in that table is equal to whatever I setup so it the new table doesn't get all the TransactionNumbers. How to do this? Thanks for helping!

```
query = select * into [bos_primary_db2].dbo.[TenderEntry] from
[bos_primary_db].dbo.[TenderEntry] 
where [TenderEntry].TransactionNumber in 
          (select TransactionNumber 
          from [bos_primary_db.dbo].[Transaction] 
          where [Transaction].Date >= '2012-2-2' 
                          and [Transaction].Date < '2012-2-3')
```

Comment: What dates do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
[Transaction].Date BETWEEN '2012-02-02' and '2012-02-03'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your String to a date:

```
where [Transaction].Date >= cast('2012.2.2' as date,102) and [Transaction].Date < cast('2012.2.3' as Date,102 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WHERE
select TransactionNumber 
      from [bos_primary_db.dbo].[Transaction] 
      where Convert(VARCHAR, [Transaction].Date,103) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR,'02/02/2012' ,103)
      and  CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Transaction].Date,103) < CONVERT(VARCHAR,'03/02/2012',103)
```